# Exporting from a pdf to an image creates jaggies

Tags: pdf

we have a PDF file with our company logo and header etc - and I'm trying to export to insert into Word.

Using Adobe Acrobat, I save it to a jpeg, using highest quality and DPI600. The file is around 1.2MB (still too large for my liking!) but the logo and text are very slightly jaggy.

At 300dpi, its very jaggy.

Is this normal? How can I get an image output from Adobe, where the quality looks comparable (at reasonable sizes).

Thanks.

edit: including 2 examples

[here's the actual pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w0jdfznjyvdw7b4/test%20document%20for%20SE.pdf)

[jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IXgf.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Which version of acrobat are you using? If you're using Acrobat X, you can export the images contained in the PDF. This will give you (and us) a better understanding of what assets you're working with.

1. Open the PDF in Acrobat X
2. Select Tools > Document Processing > Export All Images
3. Pick a save location and all the images will be saved there.

From there you could try importing the correct image into Word, if it's still jaggy upload the image and the PDF here and someone may be able to provide more insight.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. When doing that, I get the message "acrobat could not extract any images from this document. Only images that contain bitmap or raster data can be extracted." I'm using AA XI 11.

Comment: I've updated with 2 images - the pdf crop, and the exported jpg. Thanks!

Comment: and finally, updated with actual pdf link